# Regarding moving my application from libssh to libssh2

Tags: libssh2, libssh

I have few doubts/issues in moving my applications from 'libssh-0.4' to 'libssh2-1.4.3'.
I have searched and read documents related to libssh2, but was unable to find one which
throws light on moving my applications. Basically i need libssh equivalent functions in
libssh2, if some functions available in libssh are missing in libssh2 then will there be
anyway i can get the same functionality using other functions in libssh2. For example
there is no function to get banner in libssh2 but there exists one in libssh
('char *ssh_get_banner(SSH_SESSION *session);') and to my knowledge there is no function
to get banner in libssh2. And finally is it really possible for moving my application from
libssh to libssh2 with only few changes (like equivalent functions replacing) or do i need
to modify my application depending on the functionality available in libssh2.

Please suggest your ideas on this. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kumar.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use libssh 0.6.3? The feature set of libssh is a lot larger than what libssh2 provides.

Comment: braden: libssh is LGPL, not GPL